# Series in this sync have already been synced to Codex by another time series sync

Tags: time-series, synchronization, palantir-foundry

I have created an object set titled "Temperature Measurements" using "Temperature Metadata" as the backing dataset and "Temperature_Timeseries_sync" as the time series sync.

The sync, however, fails indicating that "Previously synced series and their existing time series syncs are listed here: ri.time-series-catalog.main.sync.RID-[ABC]"

I always use an existing timeseries sync to create a new one by replacing the "~/edit/RID=[ABC]" with "~/new". Now the error is pointing at the existing sync that I used to start off of.

Here are the steps I followed:
Steps I followed to create sync for new object sets:

1. I opened an existing sync as a starting point: "https://damask.palantirfoundry.com/workspace/time-series-catalog-app/edit/ri.time-series-catalog.main.sync.RID-[ABC]"
2. I replaced the above url with "https://damask.palantirfoundry.com/workspace/time-series-catalog-app/new"
3. I selected the timeseries dataset and required time series properties
4. Saved the Sync successfully.
5. Clicked the Build button to trigger the build for sync.
6. Sync fails indicating error above.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the time series id on multiple object sets were not unique and hence the error. I modified the timeseries id to be unique and it allowed the syncs to work.